# Angular Schematics: trustedSubscriber._addParentTeardownLogic

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-schematics

I'm trying to build an Angular Schematics to help me and my team create NgRx actions fast. This is the schematics function, most of it is copied from various tutorials:

```
export default (options: CCSchematicsAction): Rule => {
    return (tree: Tree, _context: SchematicContext) => {
        const modulePath = options.modulePath.replace(/-?module$/, ""); // "shared/application-tools"
        const moduleFolder = normalize("src/app/" + modulePath); // "src/app/shared/application-tools"
        const modulePathComponents = modulePath.split("/"); // ["shared", "application-tools"]
        const moduleIdentifier = modulePathComponents
            .map(part => classify(part))
            .join(".")
        + ".Action"; // "Shared.ApplicationTools.Action"

        const action = options.name.replace(/-?action$/, "");
        const path = normalize(moduleFolder + "/action/" + action) + "/";

        const templateSource = apply(url("./files"), [
            template({
                action: action,
                moduleIdentifier: moduleIdentifier
            }),
            move(path)
        ]);

        return chain([
            mergeWith(templateSource)
        ])(tree, _context);
    };
}
```

I invoke the schematics with

```
schematics cc-generate:action load-stuff-action --modulePath shared/ui
```

and get the following, which I can't even find any info to on the web:

```
TypeError: trustedSubscriber._addParentTeardownLogic is not a function
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber [as constructor] (/Users/voss/Development/cc/cc-schematics/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:45:43)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.OuterSubscriber [as constructor] (/Users/voss/Development/cc/cc-schematics/node_modules/rxjs/internal/OuterSubscriber.js:20:42)
    at new MergeMapSubscriber (/Users/voss/Development/cc/cc-schematics/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:48:28)
    at MergeMapOperator.call (/Users/voss/Development/cc/cc-schematics/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:39:33)
    at Observable.subscribe (/Users/voss/Development/cc/cc-schematics/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js:24:22)
    at DefaultIfEmptyOperator.call (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics-cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/defaultIfEmpty.js:24:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (/Users/voss/Development/cc/cc-schematics/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js:24:22)
    at TakeLastOperator.call (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics-cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/takeLast.js:35:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (/Users/voss/Development/cc/cc-schematics/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js:24:22)
    at DoOperator.call (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics-cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/tap.js:29:23)
```

**Edit:**

When I remove everything and just return an empty chain, the error stays.

```
export default (_options: CCSchematicsAction): Rule => {
    return (tree: Tree, _context: SchematicContext) => {
        return chain([noop()])(tree, _context);
    };
}
```

So what's wrong with the `chain` function?

Comment: Are you sure this is the part that throws the error? Because the stacktrace mentions operators that aren't in your code.

Comment: When I replace the `return` with a simple `return tree`, I get no error. So seems to be something going wrong with the chain. Even when I invoke the `templateSource` function just for fun (console.logging it), no error.

Answer (score 0):

Ok nevermind, the problem was the differing versions of `@angular-devkit/schematics-cli`..

Comment: Just for future reference, removing package-lock.json and reinstalling node_modules solved the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

It looks that today rxjs has released a new version 6.3.2 that solves this issue.